# How to get a field from a table twice(both on different conditions)?

Tags: mysql

I have one table called Reader with id,date,time as its fields . The time field contains both the in-time and out-time of the employees hence i would like to get retrieve the value present in time twice based on 2 conditions for a particular id and a range of dates:

```
1.In-time:Time between '9:00:00' and '12:00:00'
2.Out-time:Time between '15:00:00' and '19:00:00'
```

The Command should some what look like this

```
select id,tim,tim,dat from reader 
where tim between '09:00:00' and '14:00:00' 
and   tim between '15:00:00' and '17:00:00' 
and dat between '2011-01-17' and '2011-01-19' 
and id =10704 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,tim,dat from reader 
where ((tim between '09:00:00' and '14:00:00')
    or (tim between '15:00:00' and '17:00:00'))
and dat between '2011-01-17' and '2011-01-19' 
and id =10704 ;
```

You need an OR between the times, not AND, since it can never be possible for a time to be within TWO *non-intersecting* ranges.  Make sure to bracket that part of the condition, or your AND/ORs won't work properly.

The above gives you the data in separate rows.
To get them flat on the same record, you could use, assuming only one time in each range per day

```
select rin.id,rin.tim,rout.tim as timeout,rin.dat
from reader rin
left join reader rout on rout.id=rin.id
    and rout.tim between '15:00:00' and '17:00:00'
    and rin.dat = rout.dat
where rin.tim between '09:00:00' and '14:00:00'
and rin.dat between '2011-01-17' and '2011-01-19' 
and rin.id =10704
union all
select rout.id,rin.tim,rout.tim as timeout,rout.dat
from reader rout
left join reader rin on rout.id=rin.id
    and rin.tim between '09:00:00' and '14:00:00'
    and rin.dat = rout.dat
where rout.tim between '15:00:00' and '17:00:00'
and rout.dat between '2011-01-17' and '2011-01-19' 
and rout.id =10704
and rout.id is null
```

This special UNION ALL form emulates a FULL JOIN which is missing in MySQL.  You will get to see data even when an employee clocks in but not out or out but not in on any day.

Comment: Well the 1st one is giving only one value(time) and i did not get ur second code ...... could u give me more insight on it.... as i already said i have only 1 field time.... The  entry b/w 9-12 is in time and 3-7 is out time.... i need a way to get it

Answer (score 1):

I think that adding `AND r1.dat=r2.dat` to Thilo's code might be useful if you want to group ins and outs from one day in one row.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do it somehow like this:
(I assume you have another field giving information wether it is in or out. Otherwise, you base your query on a very weak assumption. However:

```
SELECT r1.id, r1.tim, r2.tim, r1.dat 
FROM reader AS r1, reader AS r2 
WHERE r1.id = 10704 AND r2.id = 10704
    AND r1.tim BETWEEN '09:00:00' AND '14:00:00' 
    AND r2.tim BETWEEN '15:00:00' AND '17:00:00' 
    AND r1.dat BETWEEN '2011-01-17' AND '2011-01-19';
```

Note that I put the condition for the id at the very top, assuming it is the most restrictive one and thus maybe gaining a bit of performance (Which might the query optimizer do by itself in good cases)

Cheers
Thilo

Comment: i do not have any other field specifying whether its in or out and i dont have two reader tables i have only 1

Comment: My code above does without a special field. All I wanted to say with this is basically the question: What if I already leave at 13.55? However, my query does not assume you have two different tables. You query the (same!) table reader two times and just throw all the rows together - look up the theory behind JOINs if you are not familiar with this. Afterwards we filter out all rows that match the conditions we want to filter. Royas comment is valid, though.

Comment: Then it is considered good style around here to accept the answer (by clicking the check mark on the left to the answer that helped you).